# How can I use a bluetooth controller to skip back/forward a video 5/10 seconds?

Tags: bluetooth, video, media-player

I've been trying to find an application that will skip a video backwards 5/10 seconds when I press a button on a bluetooth remote and maybe even save a bookmark to a list of bookmarks when I double click for instance play. I was able to do this on a rooted ios device using an app that remapped the forward/next track keys to short skip. I'm watching video lectures and want to control the playback. Is there any hack that will allow this in for instance VLC which already short skips when double tapping the side of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

[MX player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) has this functionality although it doesn't appear to have a bookmarking capability that can save multiple bookmarks in a video.